# Error in SOQL Query with dynamic variable containing a list in Mule 4

Tags: salesforce, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-connector

Hello I'm trying to execute an SOQL query to Salesforce but it is giving me a error while trying to add a variable that has a string of Id's inside of it.

This is the information inside the variable that I need to use :

```
[
  "a123E00000Qv6PWQAZ",
  "a123E00000Qv6PXQAZ",
  "a123E00000Qv6PYQAZ",
  "a123E00000Qv6PZQAZ",]
```

Im currently transforming it to a string like this :

```
"(" ++ ((payload.items.id map ("'" ++ $ ++"'")) joinBy ",") ++ ")"
```

Giving me this :

```
"('a123E00000Qv6PWQAZ','a123E00000Qv6PXQAZ','a123E00000Qv6PYQAZ','a123E00000Qv6PZQAZ')"
```

I want to use it this way :

```
SELECT Id FROM Company WHERE Result__c = 'Plus' AND Id NOT IN (':upserted')
```

Im currently inserting the vars.upserted in the Parameters.

When I run the flow it throws me this error when querying :

```
"
'Plus' AND Id NOT IN ('('a123E00000Qv6PWQAZ','a123E00000Qv6PXQAZ'
                                 ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:82
expecting a right parentheses, found 'a123E00000Qv6PWQAZ'"
```

Can you help in order to make the query work ?

Comment: You should add the complete operation in XML to the question for clarity. It is a bit confusing to try to connect the input to the query not seeing the parameters section of the Salesforce query operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding extra parenthesis and quotes into the query. The use of quotes in the query seems to be from a query with a single value, not for a list.

Try removing them from the query:

```sql
SELECT Id FROM Company WHERE Result__c = 'Plus' AND Id NOT IN (:upserted)
```

and from the argument:

```js
(payload map ("'" ++ $ ++"'")) joinBy ","
```

So argument `upserted` equals to `'a123E00000Qv6PWQAZ','a123E00000Qv6PXQAZ','a123E00000Qv6PYQAZ','a123E00000Qv6PZQAZ'`